# Adjusting 1 space between two strings using python

Tags: python

I have two strings:

```
>>> a = "abcd"
>>> b = "xyz"
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
abcdxyz
```

How can I get `abcd xyz` as a result instead when adding `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 23):

Simply just add a space between the two strings:

```
a = "abcd" 
b = "xyz" 
c = a + " " + b  # note the extra space concatenated with the other two
print c
```

this will give you

```
abcd xyz
```

You can use a function such as `.join()`, but for something so short, that would seem almost counter-intuitive (and IMO "overkill"). I.e., first create a list with the two strings, then call a function with that list and use the return of that function in a print statement ... when you can just concatenate the needed space with the 2 strings. Seems semantically more clear too.

Based on: "Simple is better than complex." (*The Zen of Python "import this"*)

Comment: I agree. Using `.join()` for two elements which need to be put into a list beforehand looks like overkill to me. But for longer lists of strings, it's definitely the way to go.

Comment: @TimPietzcker *Absolutely* .. I'm a big fan of `join()` myself, but for this problem it seriously is not needed.  If these were several strings for sure `join()`'s the way to go.

Comment: @Downvoter .. why the downvote? A downvote w/o explanation doesn't help *anyone* OP, SO or me and is therefore *not constructive*. Given the basic nature of the question, the solution is deliberately offered at the same level to meet OP's needs.

Answer (score 21):

You can use join to concatenate your strings together with your selected delimiter.

```
a = "abcd"
b = "xyz"
c = " ".join([a, b])
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Python 3.6, you can use f-strings to join two strings with ease. The code is more succinct and the variables are referenced directly within the context of the string.

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'world'
c = f'{a} {b}'

print(c)
```

The above code would output the following:

```
hello world
```

The `.join()` function is still the way to go when you have many strings or where the number of strings may vary.

Answer (score 3):

Python supports the [string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) and a [template system](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) (the latter is technically a simple but powerful class) as part of the string module. While the **plus** operator does its work, the lack of string formatting can influence a lot the readability of the code. A basic example for string formatting:

```
c = '%s %s' % (a, b)
```

Comment: +1 for a clever idea. -1 for using the deprecated string formatting operations instead of the new and improved `.format()` method.

Comment: With f-strings, it is now even easier: `f'{a} {b}'`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you can simply use commas within a print statement:

```py
a = "spaces"
b = "between"
c = "words"

print(a, b, c)

>>> spaces between words
```

Note, however, that this works only within the print statement. Otherwise, commas would render the expression into a tuple.

```py
s = a, b, c
print(s)
>>> ('spaces', 'between', 'words')
```

One thing you can do is to concatenate the string into a tuple, and then unpack it in the `print`

```py
print(*s)
>>> spaces between words
```