# Is it possible to change the output so that "Arlene" and "Klusman" don't have an extra set of parenthesis around them?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing code for an assignment where I can't change the main. The way I have it written, it prints like in the screenshot below:

[image: output]

Here is my code:

```
import csv

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, cust_id, name, lastName, companyName, address, city, state, cust_zip):
        self.cust_id = cust_id 
        self.first_name = name 
        self.last_name = lastName
        self.company_name = companyName
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip = cust_zip

    def getFullName(self):
        return(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def getFullAddress(self):
        return(self.getFullName(), self.company_name, self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zip)

    

def get_customers():
    myList = []
    counter = 0
    with open("customers.csv", "r") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",")
        for row in reader:
            if counter!=0:
                customer1 = Customer(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7]) 
                myList.append(customer1)  
            counter+=1
    return myList


def find_customer_by_id(customers, cust_id):
    for i in range(len(customers)):
        if cust_id == customers[i].cust_id:
            return customers[i]
    return None



def main():
    #main is fully implemented with no modification expected
    print("Customer Viewer")
    print()

    customers = get_customers()
    while True:
        cust_id = input("Enter customer ID: ").strip()
        print()

        customer = find_customer_by_id(customers, cust_id)
        if customer == None:
            print("No customer with that ID.")
            print()
        else:
            print(customer.getFullAddress())
            print()
        
        again = input("Continue? (y/n): ").lower()
        print()
        if again != "y":
            break

    print("Bye!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why are there parenthesis and, can you get rid of them?

I tried to different approaches but nothing changed the output in the intended way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049629/convert-tuple-to-string)

Comment: Find the function that returns the full name of the customer. Then make it return a string consisting of the first name and the last name separated with a space, instead of a tuple.

Comment: Alternatively, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470996/adjusting-1-space-between-two-strings-using-python

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.